# How to setup a full-text search for multiple models / data structures

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have two entities / models i would like to use in a fulltext search with azure-search:

- **Stores** (name, address, geolocation...)
- **Products** (name, weight, price...)

The user should enter a term in the fulltext search and the results of both indizes should be returned. The result is shown in seperate sections on the search result page.

At the moment I have two seperate idizes and do two search-requests.

Is there another or a better pattern to setup this search?

Comment: Are you using the results from one Search query as inputs to the other?  For example, a customer enters a term and you Search for products that match the term and then you use the product ids as input into the Store index query to return the stores that have those products?

Comment: No, they are separated. But there are stores and products which might fit the same search term. That´s the reason why I have to search in both indizes.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you could use a single index and use complex type to store the information:

```
{
   "name": "abc",
   "type": "store",
   "products":[{
     "name":"y",    
     "price": 10
   },
   "name": "x",
   "price": 24
   }]
}
```

Comment: No, that´s not what I want to achive. To stay with your store -> product relation: I would like to get a list of all stores and bellow each store I would like to show the cheapest product. So a "subselect order" on the collection of products.

Comment: I see, but you can use the same idea.inside each store, you can put an array of products. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types

Comment: Yes, but ordering by distance does not work on Collections(GeographyPoint).